# How to apply class1 functions along with the class2 functions in laravel?

Tags: laravel, bind, laravel-nova, laravel-excel, service-provider

i am using laravel-nova for my pages and laravel is the backend for development.

```
public function actions(){
  return [new DownloadExcel];
}
```

in my project nova `actions()` functions are using DownloadExcel action which is responsible for downloading the excel file for that i am using [laravel excel package](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html).

i want to convert all the cell columns as a string globally,for that i write one custom class called `customExcel.php` which extends `DownloadExcel.php`  along with that i wrote logic for converting all cells column to string inside the `customeExcel.php` file, now i  have to  change all occurrences of `actions()`like following snippet then it's working fine but i need some suggestion without changing all occurrences is there any way to load the customExcel class along with the  DownloadExcel class loaded,please give me some suggestions..

```
public function actions(){
  return [new CustomExcel];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a class is extended you only implement one object. so you need to instance again.

```php
public function actions(){
  return [new CustomExcel, new downloadExcel];
}
```

Comment: This will show two actions like `DownloadExcel` and `DownloadExcel` this is not the required answer